# How to make simple GROUP BY use index?

Tags: performance, sqlite, group-by, query-performance

I want to get average temperatures hourly for given table with temperature reads of a thermometer, with row structure: `thermometer_id, timestamp (float, julian days), value (float)` plus ascending index on `timestamp`.

To get whole day 4 days ago, I'm using this query:

```
SELECT 
    ROUND(AVG(value), 2), -- average temperature
    COUNT(*)              -- count of readings
FROM reads
WHERE 
    timestamp >= (julianday(date('now')) - 5) -- between 5 days
    AND 
    timestamp < (julianday(date('now')) - 4)  -- ...and 4 days ago
GROUP BY CAST(timestamp * 24  as int)         -- make hours from floats, group by hours
```

It does it work well, yet it works very slowly, for a 9MB database, 355k rows, it takes more than half a second to finish, which is confusingly long, it shouldn't take more than few tens of ms. It does so on not quite fast hardware (not ssd though), yet I'm preparing it to use on raspberry pi, quite slow in comparison + it's going to get 80k more rows per day of work.

`Explain` explains the reason:

"USE TEMP B-TREE FOR GROUP BY"

I've tried adding `day` and `hour` columns with indexes just for the sake of quick access, but still, group by didn't use any of the indexes.

How can I tune this query or database to make this query faster?

Comment: The cast and multiplication are likely killing any chance at using the index for grouping. If you have the latest version of SQLite (3.9.2), then you can try [creating an index on the group-by expression](http://sqlite.org/expridx.html)

Comment: Unfortunately, I've got sqlite 3.7.14 with python 2.7.3. I've created `hour` column as number with `set hour = CAST(timestamp * 24 as int)` but it's similarly slow and query planner still uses "use temp b-tree for group by".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @colonel-thirty-two commented, the problem was with cast and multiplication on `GROUP BY CAST(timestamp * 24  as int)`. Such grouping would totally omit the index, hence the slow query time. When I've used `hour` column both for time comparison and grouping, the query finished immediately.

Answer (score 1):

If an index is used to optimize the GROUP BY, the `timestamp` search can no longer be optimized (except by using the [skip-scan optimization](http://www.sqlite.org/optoverview.html#skipscan), which your old SQLite might not have). And going through *all* rows in `reads`, only to throw most of them away because of a non-matching timestamp, would not be efficient.

If SQLite doesn't automatically do the right thing, even after running [ANALYZE](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_analyze.html), you can try to force it to use a specific index:

```
CREATE INDEX rhv ON reads(hour, value);
SELECT ... FROM reads INDEXED BY rhv WHERE timestamp ... GROUP BY hour;
```

But this is unlikely to result in a query plan that is actually faster.